# Stumped with a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have lines in a file like so:

```
l_12_interval         j_10_int
Length:100         Min.   :-2120803808
Class :character   1st Qu.: -992076064
Mode  :character   Median :  263935522
                   Mean   :  -33801580
                   3rd Qu.:  896644601
                   Max.   : 1890084945
                   NA's   :53
```

I want to parse out what I'll call the last "major column":

```
   j_10_int
Min.   :-2120803808
1st Qu.: -992076064
Median :  263935522
Mean   :  -33801580
3rd Qu.:  896644601
Max.   : 1890084945
NA's   :53
```

The columns will be aligned but I can't depend on where the the last major column will start.  The heading is not a problem and I am trying to compose a regular expression for Python's `re.sub()` function to strip off everything preceding the label.  I thought I could do it by including the label and the colon in the regular expression as a subexpression and replace the matching expression with the subexpression.  Easier said than done!  This is the closest I've gotten:

```
>>> line
'       Length:100         Min.   :-2120803808'
>>> re.sub(r"^.*([a-z1-9][a-z1-9.' ]*:)", r"\1", line, re.IGNORECASE)
'n.   :-2120803808'
>>>
```

I thought I could toss a whitespace immediately before the beginning of the subexpression but that's not working:

```
>>> re.sub(r"^.*\s([a-z1-9][a-z1-9.' ]*:)", r"\1", line, re.IGNORECASE)
'       Length:100         Min.   :-2120803808'
>>> re.sub(r"^.* ([a-z1-9][a-z1-9.' ]*:)", r"\1", line, re.IGNORECASE)
'       Length:100         Min.   :-2120803808'
>>> re.sub(r"^.*( [a-z1-9][a-z1-9.' ]*:)", r"\1", line, re.IGNORECASE)
'       Length:100         Min.   :-2120803808'
>>> re.sub(r"^.*(\w[a-z1-9][a-z1-9.' ]*:)", r"\1", line, re.IGNORECASE)
'in.   :-2120803808'
```

As you can see, I even tried pulling the whitespace inside the subexpression... that would be acceptable.  But I'm still not much closer to complete solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you just want the values in the "second column"? I.e. everything after the last colon?

Comment: No, I want the label that precedes the colon too.

Comment: Find `Min.` position - for example 10th char - and remove 10 chars in all rows.

Comment: Another thought too would be to replace all extraneous characters, and use delimiters? Unless the speed of regex is really needed? (`str.split()` and `str.replace()`) And then wrangle it into a dictionary/json/yaml/pickle or something....

Answer (score 2):

This one bases quite a few assumptions about the format of names and that of the values of the first column, but it works with your example:

```
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s*:[a-z0-9]*|)\s*([A-Z0-9].*)$
```

Probably needs a bit more work based on what you know exactly about the formats of the different names and values.

Demo:
http://regex101.com/r/oP3pT2

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a regular expression and the columns have a fixed width the following example should also work for you.

```
with open("data", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip("\n")[19:])
```

This will output:

```
   j_10_int
Min.   :-2120803808
1st Qu.: -992076064
Median :  263935522
Mean   :  -33801580
3rd Qu.:  896644601
Max.   : 1890084945
NA's   :53
```

Comment: This assumes the what I want starts in column 19 but that is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Ide rather not write python regexes.

So if this is a one time job, then I have a perl oneliner for you.

```
perl -pe 's/^\w++\s++(\w++)/\t$1/||s/.*?\s*+:\s*+\w++\s++(.*)/$1/||s/\s++(.*)/$1/' FILE.txt > NEWFILE.txt
```

That produces the desired output in from file `FILE.txt` to file `NEWFILE.txt`

I hope that was useful.

The trick is looking for junk before a `:` followed by possible whitespace and a single group of word characters then followed by some space.  Everything after that on a line like that is what you are looking for.

I also handled other cases like the first line and stripping leading whitespace on some lines.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the values in the next to last column can't contan spaces because in this case, in general, it's impossible to distinguish headers in our column from values in previous column. This is shown in the (imaginary) example:

```
Length:100    Ticks   Min.   :-2120803808
Class :char   Acter   1st Qu.: -992076064
Mode  :char   Acter   Median :  263935522
```

Assuming that values after colon can't contain spaces (or we have at least one without spaces) I would suggest to find the margin of the last column just as we do it by our eyes: statistically, finding indent that looks like beginning of the alligned column everywhere in file. Here is possible implementation:

```
import re
import itertools

with open('stat.txt', 'r') as sf:
    next(sf)            # Skip headers.
    lines = list(sf)    # Read file to memory.

# Find the last colon and the next-to-last one.
lc = lines[0].rfind(':')
nlc = lines[0].rfind(':', 0, lc)

# Collect indents statistics.
indents = {}
for line in lines:
    words = re.finditer('([\w\.]+)', line[nlc+1:lc])
    for match in words:
        indent = match.start()
        if indent in indents:
            indents[indent] += 1
        else:
            indents[indent] = 1

# Find most "popular" indent. Assumed to be only one.
pi_freq = max(indents.values())
pi_idxs = itertools.filterfalse(
    lambda x: indents[x] != pi_freq or x == 0, indents.keys())
pi_val = next(pi_idxs)

# WE HAVE FOUND IT!
last_col_idx = nlc + pi_val + 1

# And now we are ready.
for line in lines:
    print(line[last_col_idx:], end='')
```

Of course it's not necessary to read file in memory if you don't like it. We can simply access it twice.